Room filling a map<String, Object>
My table (MyTable) have the following columns:
id, name, city, street, zipcode
My data class is:
data class Address(
city:String,
street:String,
zipcode:String,
)

What i want is to write a dao query to retrive the address in the form of a Map<name, address>. Doing a simple select does not work.
@Query("SELECT ... FROM MyTable .... WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun getAddress(id: Long):Map<String,Address>

Update:
I think I got it working.
I had to use @MapColumn
Map<@MapColumn(columnName = "name") String, Address>

